# How to refresh a eclipse project built from ant build file?

Tags: eclipse

I created a new project in eclipse using an existing ant build file (using the eclipse feature).

Is there a way to refresh the project, if the ant build file is modified?

For example, there were new build path dependencies added to the `build.xml` but in eclipse those files were not added to the project build path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe once the project has been created you have to keep them up to sync manually.  Either that, or delete the project in eclipse and create a New project from the newly updated ant file.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I guess as you said, there's no way to refresh the project from ant file after the project is created.